# Vagrant Windows - ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: windows, ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

It seems I can't SSH to my virtual box.

I have a virtual box running with Win7. The host PC is also in Win7.
The virtual box was created through Vagrant with the following Vagrantfile.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|  
    config.vm.box = "http://aka.ms/vagrant-win7-ie11"  
end
```

Open cmd. Go to the root folder of the VagrantFile.
Execute the following command:

```
vagrant up
```

cmd displays:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...  
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...  
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...  
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...  
    default: Adapter 1: nat  
==> default: Forwarding ports...  
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)  
==> default: Booting VM...  
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...  
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant  
    default: SSH auth method: private key

Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot...
```

Time out appears though the virtual box has already finished the boot. (Checking via VirtualBox Manager)

Execute the following command:

```
vagrant ssh
```

cmd displays:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

While debugging the vagrant ssh, I may have found some useful logs:

```
INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin/ssh.EXE"]

INFO ssh: Invoking SSH: ss ["vagrant@127.0.0.1", "-p", "2222", "-o", "Compression=yes", "-o", "DSAAuthentication=yes", "-o", "LogLevel=FATAL", "-o", "StrictHostKeyChecking=no", "-o", "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null", "-o", "IdentitiesOnly=yes", "-i", "C:/Users/hostpcname/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"]
```

Can you suggest some ways on how to get out of this?
I've tried the non-Windows image - hashicorp/precise64, and it worked fine.

Comment: Same error. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 12):

I have the same issue. Do by follow this step and working for me.

> vagrant reload

and

> vagrant ssh

again and working fine

Comment: this is just a temporary solution, the problem comes back. this does not fix anything..

Comment: I am facing the same issue. But this one doesnt fixed mine.

Answer (score 2):

These steps will work

1. vagrant halt
2. open virtual box and uncheck hardware virtualization , save it
3. vagrant up
4. vagrant ssh

Note:  vagrant halt is must, settings can't be edited in running state

[image]

Comment: how can I get the vagrant machine being displayed in virtualbox?

Answer (score 1):

The following commands worked for me.

> ```
> vagrant halt
> vagrant up
> vagrant ssh
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Enable de virtualization on BIOS

Comment: how can I enable it?

Comment: https://docs-old.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Virtualization_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html

Answer (score 0):

After rebooting my computer and enabling intel virtualization in BIOS, I was able to get past this.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting error  as :  ssh_exchange_identification connection reset by peer 
Please follow below link ,it worked for me.
 https://talk.openmrs.org/t/error-on-vagrant-up/8833/30

Step:

Please open virtualbox and check if any vm is running.

Run vagrant destroy to remove all vms created by current Vagrantfile.
Remove .vagrant directory in the bahmni-vagrant directory.
Make sure you have the same Vagrantfile file as https://github.com/Bahmni/bahmni-vagrant/blob/master/Vagrantfile 37.
Run vagrant up. Monitor virtualbox while it is starting up.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
 [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) .