# vagrant ssh get error: ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: vagrant, buildroot

I'm installing buildroot. But when I fllow the manual from buildroot doc, the error occurred.

This is my process.

```
curl -O https://buildroot.org/downloads/Vagrantfile; vagrant up
```

And the results are as fllows.

```
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
    default: Guest communication could not be established! This is usually because
    default: SSH is not running, the authentication information was changed,
    default: or some other networking issue. Vagrant will force halt, if
    default: capable.
==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/bionic64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
```

Then I try to connect with ssh

```
vagrant ssh
```

But there is northing to show. Just like this.

```
lt@ubuntu:~/qemu/buildroot$ vagrant ssh
```

So I try ssh command.

```
lt@ubuntu:~/qemu/buildroot$ vagrant ssh-config
```

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/lt/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 i /home/lt/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

However, also northing to show.

Could you give me a sultion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try performing the following commands:

1. `vagrant halt`
2. `vagrant up`
3. `vagrant ssh`

This should fix the issue. If it still persists, check your bios settings to ensure that virtualization is enabled. If your on windows, make sure hyper-v is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Its a duplicate question and answered multiple times

You can refer my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62928259/6150566

Answer (score 0):

Enable Virtualization by going to BIOS if you are on Windows.
If you are running VirtualBox inside a nested VM, you can enable the Virtualization settings (VT-X) by powering off the VM.